# CMake Error: Project 'nav_core' tried to find library '-lpthread'

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap-2d, nav-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't to build navigation stack (https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation).
My system is: Ubuntu 16.04 4.15.0-43-generic, ROS Kinetic.
What I do:

```
mkdir -p navigation_ws/src
cd navigation_ws/src
catkin_init_workspace
git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation
cd ..
catkin_make
```

The error message is:

```
CMake Error at /home/username/navigation_ws/devel/share/costmap_2d/cmake/costmap_2dConfig.cmake:148 (message):
  Project 'nav_core' tried to find library '-lpthread'.  The library is
  neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
  'costmap_2d'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing
  its code is included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  navigation/nav_core/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

Then I found that '-l-lpthread' instead of '-lpthread' presents in files: devel/lib/pkgconfig/costmap_2d.pc, build/navigation/costmap_2d/catkin_generated/pkg.installspace.context.pc.py, build/navigation/costmap_2d/catkin_generated/pkg.develspace.context.pc.py and build/navigation/costmap_2d/catkin_generated/installspace/costmap_2d.pc

Please, help to solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313895/cmake-error:-project-%27nav_core%27-tried-to-find-library-%27-lpthread%27/) by [standmit](https://answers.ros.org/users/39694/standmit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-27**:
I believe this is a duplicate of #q311753 and #q311685, although you're using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was caused by wrong cmake version

---

Originally posted by [standmit](https://answers.ros.org/users/39694/standmit/) with karma: 28 on 2019-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yummy_Ou](https://answers.ros.org/users/49728/yummy_ou/) on 2019-12-11**:
Hi! I also have this problem, my ROS still is CMake 3.5.1. But because I upgrade CMake to 3.15.3, so now when I run "cmake --version", it shows me that 3.15.3.
Does that mean I should downgrade CMake?

**Comment by [Yummy_Ou](https://answers.ros.org/users/49728/yummy_ou/) on 2019-12-11**:
I solve it! [In my link](https://answers.ros.org/question/339641/cant-find-library-pthread/)
It is because of the higher version!
Thanks~

**Comment by [standmit](https://answers.ros.org/users/39694/standmit/) on 2019-12-12**:
I has checked several versions of CMake, and has found that 'navigation' successfully builds with CMake up to 3.13.2 inclusive

**Comment by [Yummy_Ou](https://answers.ros.org/users/49728/yummy_ou/) on 2019-12-12**:
interesting... thanks for your information!